# How can I tracing method call following the ordering?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-interception

I would like to tracing the method calls following the order. Because the logging will be applied on the production so I do not want to modify my code so much.

So far, I would like to apply an interceptor on Unity to tracing the method call, I almost done. However, the log printing out is not what I am expecting. All of I need are:

From peusedo code as below:

```
  void method1()
  {
     call method2();
  }
```

The tracing log should be format as below:

Entering Method call 1/ 
Entering Method call 2

Leaving Method call 2 /
Leaving Method call 1

BTW, my application running on .Net framework version 4.

The program as below:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IInterface1, Implementation1>();
        container.RegisterType<IInterface2, Implementation2>();
        container.RegisterInstance(typeof (IUnityContainer), container);
        container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();

        container.Configure<Interception>()
        .SetInterceptorFor<IInterface1>(new InterfaceInterceptor());

        container.Configure<Interception>()
        .SetInterceptorFor<IInterface2>(new InterfaceInterceptor());

        var service = container.Resolve<IInterface1>();
        var results = service.GetListCustomerIdByName("abc");

        Console.ReadLine();
     }

public interface IInterface1
    {
        [Trace]
        IEnumerable<Guid> GetListCustomerIdByName(string name);
    }

    public class Implementation1 : IInterface1
    {
        private readonly IInterface2 _impl;

        public Implementation1(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            _impl = container.Resolve<IInterface2>();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Guid> GetListCustomerIdByName(string name)
        {
            return _impl.GetListCustomerIdByName(name);
        }
    }

public interface IInterface2
{
    [Trace]
    IEnumerable<Guid> GetListCustomerIdByName(string name);
}

public class Implementation2 : IInterface2
{
    public IEnumerable<Guid> GetListCustomerIdByName(string name)
    {
        yield return Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}


public class TraceAttribute : HandlerAttribute
    {
        public override ICallHandler CreateHandler(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            return new TraceCallHandler();
        }
    }

public class TraceCallHandler : ICallHandler
{
    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, 
   GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entering " + input.MethodBase.Name +"()");

        InvokeHandlerDelegate next = getNext();

        IMethodReturn result = next(input, getNext);

        string returnValueStr = 
        result.ReturnValue == null ? "(void)" : result.ReturnValue.ToString();

        if (result.Exception != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", result.Exception);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Leaving 
        " +input.MethodBase.Name + "() Return Value: [" + returnValueStr + "]");

        return result;
    }

    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

Sorry for my code. It is quite long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a class provides that functionality:

```
class Scope : IDisposable
{
    Action<string> _logger;
    string _memberName;

    public Scope(Action<string> logger, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "N/A")
    {
        if (logger == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

        _logger = logger;
        _memberName = memberName;

        _logger(string.Format("Entered {0}", _memberName));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _logger(string.Format("Exited {0}", _memberName));
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
static void MyMethod()
{
    using (new Scope(s => Console.WriteLine(s)))
    {
        // boddy
    }
}
```

Note: If you use previous versions of C# that does not support `[CallerMemberName]` attribute, you have to provide `memberName` explicitly.

Also you can use this helper class that I use myself in version prior to .NET 4.5:

```
public static class Here
{
    public static string Spot(HereOptions options)
    {
        return MakeMessageInternals(options, 3);
    }

    public static string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return MakeMessageInternals(HereOptions.Type, 3);
        }
    }

    public static string Member
    {
        get
        {
            return MakeMessageInternals(HereOptions.Member, 3);
        }
    }

    public static string FileLine
    {
        get
        {
            return MakeMessageInternals(HereOptions.FileLine, 3);
        }
    }

    public static string FileName
    {
        get
        {
            return MakeMessageInternals(HereOptions.FileName, 3);
        }
    }

    static StackFrame GetCaller(int index) { return new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(index); }

    static string MakeMessageInternals(HereOptions options, int index)
    {
        StackFrame first = null;
        var _FileName = new StringBuilder();
        var _FileLine = new StringBuilder();
        var _Member = new StringBuilder();
        var _Type = new StringBuilder();

        if ((options & HereOptions.FileName) == HereOptions.FileName)
        {
            first = GetCaller(index);
            if (first != null)
            {
                var fn = first.GetFileName();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fn))
                    _FileName.Append(" " + Path.GetFileName(fn));
            }
        }

        if ((options & HereOptions.FileLine) == HereOptions.FileLine)
        {
            if (first == null)
                first = GetCaller(index);
            if (first != null)
            {
                var ln = first.GetFileLineNumber();
                _FileLine.Append(" #" + ln);
            }
        }

        if ((options & HereOptions.Member) == HereOptions.Member)
        {
            if (first == null)
                first = GetCaller(index);
            if (first != null)
            {
                var mn = first.GetMethod().Name;
                _Member.Append(" " + mn);
            }
        }

        if ((options & HereOptions.Type) == HereOptions.Type)
        {
            if (first == null)
                first = GetCaller(index);
            if (first != null)
            {
                var dt = first.GetMethod().DeclaringType;
                _Type.Append(string.Format(" ({0})", dt));
            }
        }

        var messageInternal = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}",
            _FileName,
            _FileLine,
            _Member,
            _Type).Trim();

        return messageInternal;
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum HereOptions : byte
{
    None = 0,
    FileName = 1,
    FileLine = 2,
    Member = 4,
    Type = 8,
    All = 15
}
```

Comment: That's mean every method call, I will add the using(Scope logger ... and I am not sure it will print out correct order method call if there is many nested method calls inside. Anyway, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: It will print out correct method call not matter how deep is your nested calls as long as you are not doing parallel programming. I use a more sophisticated version of this class myself. I did not found a better way (There is a way: using PostSharp and employing aspect oriented programming; but I do not like it). Sorry I was disappointing! :)

Comment: one more reason I will not apply your answer is your code only available for .Net framework version 4.5. My code running on .Net framework version 4. BTW, I will +1 for your answer may be someone will be help from your answer.

Comment: I figure out the way around base on your answer. I found the link http://www.journeyintocode.com/2013/04/callermembername-net-40.html to work around CallerMemberName feature. Many thanks for your idea. I will accept this is a correct answer.

Comment: I have already have a tool for that. I've added to the answer.

Comment: And I am happy that it was of help! :)